# Error sending message in production app in RingCentral

Tags: c#, sms, ringcentral

I have integrated sending messages using RingCentral in my system. The messages were being sent successfully using the sandbox app and number, but it gives an error for production app and main company number.

The error is as below:

```
{
  "errorCode" : "FeatureNotAvailable",
  "message" : "Phone number doesn't belong to extension",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "MSG-304",
    "message" : "Phone number doesn't belong to extension"
  } ]
}
```

I have referred to following [link](https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev/topics/send-sms-error-msg-304?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all) in community, but can't get what the reference links say. I have tried to look in for solutions given in this thread but it doesn't seem to lead any where.

I have also tried logging in with different extensions and sendmessage through the only number I have in my developer portal console.

Comment: I have read the answers and have one more question. Can I send SMS using any sms enabled extension if I have authorized my Ringcentral app with main company number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone numbers used in the production and sandbox environments are different because they are associated with your production and sandbox accounts.

When you move your app from sandbox to production you need to change the phone numbers used (along with the application credentials).

To see what phone numbers you can use, make a `GET` call to the the following API endpoint and then look for numbers with the `SmsSender` feature.

`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/phone-number`

An easy way to call this us to use the `accountId` and `extensionId` for the current access token by using `~` like:

`/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/phone-number`

The response will include an array of phone numbers with a `features` array property. Phone numbers the authorizing user can use to send SMS will have the `SmsSender` feature. You should verify that the number you are using is in the list and has the feature.

```
{  
  "uri":"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/phone-number?page=1&perPage=100",
  "records":[
    {
      "id":33333333,
      "phoneNumber":"+16505551212",
      "paymentType":"Local",
      "type":"VoiceFax",
      "usageType":"DirectNumber",
      "features":[
        "SmsSender",
        "CallerId"
      ],
      "status":"Normal",
      "country":{
        "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/country/1",
        "id":"1",
        "name":"United States"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

More information on SMS including using the Main Company Phone Number is in the RingCentral Developer Guide section on SMS:

http://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages_sms-and-pager/

You can also manually verify which account your number belongs to by logging into the respective Online Account Portals:

- Production Online Account Portal: https://service.ringcentral.com
- Sandbox Online Account Portal: https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response, I will check for SmsSender feature. I have checked main number extension in RingCentral service portal and it has SMS enabled in admin portal.

Comment: I just made a check on SMSsender feature with my production credentials. I found a list of phone numbers with Main Company Phone Number, none has SMSsender feature. I have read this [link](http://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages_sms-and-pager/#sms-and-the-main-company-number) also on setting Main Company Number to Operator Extension. I don't want to set main number as Operator Extension. In auto receptionist section in production admin portal, under section "Company Fax/SMS Recipient" I have an extension assigned. Can you tell me how to use that extension to send SMS?

Comment: If you don't have any numbers that can send SMS in your production account, we should understand why that is the case and how you can get one which may be tied to the type of account you have. All US accounts have SMS (https://www.ringcentral.com/office/plansandpricing.html). Please join our support chat here and I'll be able to assist more after getting some account info from you: https://glipped.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thanks, I will make further inquiries there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send SMS from your production environment (using a production phone number), you have to graduate your app to production then change use the production app credentials (client ID and secret) as well as production user login credentials (extension phone number and password).

Remember that you cannot send SMS using a phone number which does not belong to the extension you logged in for the app.

- Paco

Comment: I am using my production app credentials (client ID and secret) and production user login credentials (main phone number and password) for authorization. I am also sending message from the main number that I have authToken of.